# jquery to make a div floating at the bottom right corner

Tags: jquery

Hello i am relatively new to jquery but i like it, was wondering if i can have a **floating div at the bottom right corner of the page(*using jquery*)** so that it regains it's position even when we scroll down the page. Thereafter i need to pass a link through an image in the div to a specific anchor in the page. It should be short and simple.
Although it can be accomplished using css but ie does not support position:fixed **so only jquery**

Answer (score 3):

Position fixed can be achieved in IE even without jquery: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/

Otherwise this works too: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/FixedIE

Comment: both links are broken.